spring data jpa ORA-01795: maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT rh FROM RoleHead rh, RoleDmdLine rl" 
+ " where rh.id=rl.id" + " and rl.id in (:roleListId)"
Iterable <RoleHead> findAllByLıne(@param("roleListId")List<Long>roleListId);

The problem is that I am passing a very big list and I get back an ORA-01795 error.
I haven't reached a conclusion yet

Refer to below question with detail explaination

@ShriramUntawale that is related but different question.

as a crutch:
you can spli your list to multiple one
""" AND (rl.id in (:roleListId) or rl.id in (:roleListId2) or rl.id in (:roleListId3)) """

Another option is to store all those elements into a table, so query would then look like e.g.
select distinct rh
from rolehead rh join roledmdline rl on rh.id = rl.id
                 join your_new_table nt on nt.id = rl.id

or
select distinct rh
from rolehead rh join roledmdline rl on rh.id = rl.id
where rl.id in (select nt.id from your_new_table nt)

or
select distinct rh
from rolehead rh join roledmdline rl on rh.id = rl.id
where exists (select null
              from your_new_table nt
              where nt.id = rl.id)


You have to split your list in batches no more than 1000 elements and then combine results.
